# How do we get the Borel sets / sigma-fields?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am doing mathematical finance, and the authors always try to motivate the mathematical foundations of probability.

Often they roughly explain measure, and then talk about Lebesgue measure over, say, $[0,1]$.  Then they make a statement like "*the sigma algebra by beginning with the closed intervals and adding everything else we need to have a sigma algebra is called the Borel $\sigma$-algebra*".

I'm never quite sure what that means.  At the simples, since complements exist, we can get open intervals trivially using complement, intersection and union.

But I always feel like I am missing something in what I understand, or what is being explained.  If we had the closed intervals with Lebesgue measure, why do we not have a sigma algebra?  If things are "missing", exactly what are they, and is it always true we can add then with simply complement, intersection, and union?  And, when we do so, is that the only sigma algebra that can come from closed intervals over $[0,1]$, or could others be built?

Comment: It's the $\sigma$-algebra generated by open intervals.  (It's any *countable* unions of (open intervals and/or their complements).)

Comment: In the $\sigma$-algebra generated by open/closed intervals, you can even get things like the Cantor set, since it can be expressed as countable intersections and unions, which is not a closed interval. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra is thus the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that includes the closed intervals, but the closed intervals is a strict subset of it. The key word here is the sigma algebra is _generated_ by the intervals.